# .NET/Visual Studio: How to find NuGet Package Source for a given Package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have inherited a project recently and a select few of the packages originated from a package source that I do not know the source url to connect to. Is there a way to, by looking at the solution, tell the URL/source that these packages came from? Unfortunately, the previous owner of the solution is not being very responsive or helpful.

I've tried looking in `packages.config` which only seems to list the package id and version for each package along with browsing through `.csproj` and `.sln` files

Comment: Not, as far as I know. You can simply swith between feeds, and the IDE will look only at the version. No package source information is kept with the project itself.

Comment: Hopefully they were not using a private local package repository.

Comment: @BradleyUffner it was privately hosted but publicly available is all the information I have. Was really hoping there was a way to hunt down where it was hosted

Comment: Can you share the package name and ID?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've found it- thanks anyways. There are 4 projects in the solution and each has a  `/.nuget/nuget.config`file. 3 of the 4 were scrubbed and 1 was left including the package source I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in the future, I've found where the reference to the package source is stored in the `ProjectName/.nuget/nuget.config` file. Note, this will only be helpful if you are given a copy of a project and this file is not scrubbed beforehand.